# performance issues executing list of stored procedures

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, loops

I'm having some performance issues when starting my windows service, the first round my lstSps is long (about 130 stored procedures). Is there anyway to speed this up (except for speeding the stored procedures up)?

When the foreach is over and goes over to the second round it goes faster, because there aren't that many returning true on TimeToRun(). But, my concern is about the first time, when there are a lot more stored procedures to run.

I have though about making a array and a for loop since I read that its faster, but I believe the problem is because the procedures takes to long time. Could I build this in a better way? Maybe use multiple threads (one for each execute) or something like that?

Would really appreciate some tips :)

EDIT: Just to clarify, it's method HasResult() is executing the SP:s and makes to look taking time..

```
lock (lstSpsToSend)
{
    lock (lstSps)
    {
        foreach (var sp in lstSps.Where(sp => sp .TimeToRun()).Where(sp => sp.HasResult()))
        {
            lstSpsToSend.Add(sp);
        }
    }
}

while (lstSpsToSend.Count > 0)
{
    //Take the first watchdog in list and then remove it
    Sp sp;
    lock (lstSpsToSend)
    {
        sp = lstSpsToSend[0];
        lstSpsToSend.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    try
    {
        //Send the results
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as you didn't profiled it, we can't help you for real...

Comment: The help I want is not speeding up all stored procedures, but finding a better way to execute them so I don't have do 1. Execute all stored procedures (wait until all is finished) 2. Start processing the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is something like this:

```
int openThread = 0;
ConcurrentQueue<Type> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Type>();
foreach (var sp in lstSps)
{
    Thread worker = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref openThread);
            if(sp.TimeToRun() && sp.HasResult)
            {
                queue.add(sp);
            }
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref openThread);
        }) {Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal, IsBackground = false};
        worker.Start();
}
// Wait for all thread to be finnished
while(openThread > 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}

// And here move sp from queue to lstSpsToSend

while (lstSpsToSend.Count > 0)
{
    //Take the first watchdog in list and then remove it
    Sp sp;
    lock (lstSpsToSend)
    {
        sp = lstSpsToSend[0];
        lstSpsToSend.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    try
    {
        //Send the results
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you did there, are you creating a new thread for each SP? Why should this improve performance?

Comment: You said that it was the `TimeToRun()` that was slowing down your stuff, if you put it on different thread and let the system parallelize the computing, you'll save time. I could also have use a `Parallel.ForEach`. But maybe I *totally* misread the question... @krillezzz

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. It is HasResult() that executes the SP:s and making to loop taking time.

Comment: @krillezzz that's the same, both are now executing in parallel and should save you some time

Comment: @krillezzz how much win?

Comment: More than 90 sec, now it took 30 sec and before around 2min

Comment: With those results I would assume you have a few SP's that are heavy hitters and most are lightweight.  You could add logging to see what the longest running procedures are and see if there's anything you can do about them.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would rely heavily on what these stored procedures are actually doing, If they are returning the same kind of result set, or no result for that matter, it would definitely be beneficial to send them to SQL server all at once instead of one at a time.

The reason for this is network latency, if your SQL server sits in a data center somewhere that you are accessing over a WAN, your latency could be anywhere from 200ms up. So if you are calling 130 stored procedures sequentially, the "cost" would be 200ms X 130. That's 26 seconds just running back and forth over a network connection not actually executing the logic in your proc.

If you can combine all the procedures into a single call, you pay the 200ms cost only once.

Executing them on multiple concurrent threads is also a reasonable approach, but as before it would depend on what your procedures are doing and returning back to you.

Using an array over a list would not really give you any performance increases.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: The SP:s are returning a XML if they have a hit, otherwise they return nothing. If there is a hit then the XML is processed later.

Comment: Then definitely try and combine them into one SQL call.

Comment: But how do I attach the result to my Sp object when executing them all at once?

Comment: Return all of the results in one go as a DataTable